# Custom From Address in List Alerts

Tags: email, alert, custom, collaboration

We are using host-named site collections in our environment sharing one web application. The problem is that when a user set alerts on their lists/items in their sites, they receive the alerts from whatever email address configured in the web application level. And that's is not OK with them. Each team want to have the team email in the from field in the email message.

So, is there away to make the alert pick a custom email address in the email-from instead of the one defined globally on the web application level?

Answer (score 1):

Not with the OOTB Alerts, they will always use the web app from/reply to email.

To do this you're going to have to create your own alerts using something like workflow, event receivers or a timer service/job.